# Stuck on a minesweeper supposedly solvable through pure deduction

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction, minesweeper

I'm playing minesweeper on a website that says you can win using pure deduction without guessing, and I am currently stuck in the top left corner of the map. It's a 30x16 grid with 170 mines and the rest of the grid is solved. Is this possible without guessing? Since there are  5  blocks on the top left corner that are not bound by any numbers they can be used to pick different possible outcomes for the remaining 9 mines that all work based off the scenarios I tried imagining.

One thing I concluded was that in order for the pair in the top to be solvable by deduction they either both have to be mines or both have to be clear. I'm not sure if that is 100% true.

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Row 3, column 2 is safe because of the 4.